# TeeChart Contour lines color

Tags: java, android, contour, teechart

I use TeeChart JAVA for Android to create a contour.

```
Series series = Series.createNewSeries(mChart.getChart(), Contour.class, null);
mContour = (Contour) series;

mContour.setAutomaticLevels(true);
mContour.setNumLevels(15);
```

The color transition from blue to white is set by default to draw contour lines. I need to change it from red to green. So the largest value will be red and the smallest one will be green.

This is what happens by default:
[image: This is what happens by default]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change ColorRange settings, for example:

```
tChart1.getAspect().setView3D(false);

Contour series1 = new Contour(this.tChart1.getChart());

series1.fillSampleValues();

series1.setUseColorRange(true);
series1.setUsePalette(false);
series1.setStartColor(Color.GREEN);
series1.setEndColor(Color.RED);
series1.setMidColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```